# Finding a column name which bears the same name as a row value then change row values from that column onwards to NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, subset, apply

I have a big data frame, one of the columns have levels which bears same values as the column names( e.g  df[1,3]= 22/05/2020,  has the same value as column 4, = 22/05/2020. I want to replace values in row 1 to NA, but only those which come after a column 4. This has to be applied to a big dataset. If data entries for row 1 are; 23 21 33 45 7 11 26, I would want to convert all values after column 4 to NA, = 23 21 33 45 NA NA NA*

"A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16"),
TPK = c("8/12/2020", "8/12/2020", "8/1/2021", "8/1/2021",
"8/12/2020", "8/1/2021", "8/1/2021", "25/11/2020", "24/10/2020",
"24/10/2020", "16/10/2020", "16/10/2020", "16/10/2020", "16/10/2020",
"16/10/2020", "16/10/2020"), TCL = c("9/6/2021", "8/6/2021",
"16/6/2021", "10/6/2021", "10/6/2021", "23/5/2021", "7/6/2021",
"3/5/2021", "17/5/2021", "19/6/2021", "30/4/2021", "27/4/2021",
"6/6/2021", "4/5/2021", "30/4/2021", "3/5/2021"), TFN = c(183L,
182L, 159L, 153L, 184L, 135L, 150L, 159L, 205L, 238L, 196L,
193L, 233L, 200L, 196L, 199L), BBC = c("15_Map", "16_Map",
"17_Map", "22_Map", "77_Map", "18_Map", "30_Map", "15_Map",
"56_Map", "16_Map", "17_Map", "18_Map", "23_Map", "20_Map",
"13_Map", "14_Map"), X12_Map = c(39L, 36L, 37L, 33L, 39L,
27L, 31L, 42L, 34L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 43L, 33L, 39L, 41L), X13_Map = c(39L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 0L,
0L), X14_Map = c(0L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 37L), X15_Map = c(0L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 0L, 0L), X16_Map = c(0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 42L, 0L, 37L, 0L,
0L), X17_Map = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X18_Map = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 37L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X19_Map = c(0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 40L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L), X20_Map = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 34L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
40L, 40L, 0L, 42L, 0L, 0L), X21_Map = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 42L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-16L))```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data rather than describing it. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're missing something at the beginning of your code, because it doesn't work. I'm also unclear what the column names should be? I [recently asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72611249/vectorizing-a-for-loop-that-changes-columns-of-a-matrix/72639150?noredirect=1#comment128326589_72639150) and found a good solution in using the `matrixStats::rowCumsums` function.

Theoretically, you'd look for the value in the column equal to colnames(), then set the values equal to NA, then you could use the above function. Without better data I can't give a full answer.